# Probability of not b given a

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a probability problem and I'm not sure how to answer it, some told me that it was with a probability of not b given a, but I'm not sure how to do it and if it's correct the problem is

57% of the university students live afar from the university, 40% of the students use public transport to go to university, and 37% of students live afar and use public transport

A) If one student is randomly chosen of those that liver afar, What is the probability that they use a different transport than public transport?

I have done this but I think it's wrong, as the result is more than 1

P(A) = 0.57

P(B) = 0.40

P(A ∩ B) = 0.37

P(B’)= not b

P(B’/ A) = 1 - P(B/A) = 1-P(A ∩ B)/P(A)

1-P(A ∩ B)/P(A) = 1- 0,37/0,57

1-P(A ∩ B)/P(A) = 0,63/0,57

1-P(A ∩ B)/P(A) =  1,10

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It will be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, what you have tried, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: Hint to get started: if 57% of all students live afar, and if 37% of all students live afar and use public transportation, then what percentage of all students live afar and don’t use public transportation?

Comment: Your mistake is that you went from 1-(0.37/0.57) to (1-0.37)/0.57

Comment: Ohhh of course that's my mistake, always divide first, sometimes basic math goes over my head

Comment: LOL. Hey, you did everything else correct!